# Laravel truncating strings with special characters

Tags: mysql, laravel, special-characters, truncate, htmlspecialchars

I have been working on a CMS for months now, I have faced various challenges with laravel truncating certain special characters. I had to change the editor in the CMS from bootstrap wysiwyg to ckeditor things got quite better as there are some advance escaping options that come with it.
For example I was able to prevent `'"'` from becoming `'&quot;` which was causing the entire string (paragraph) to truncate where ever it finds such encoding.

However this is a CMS where the user has a good reason to input a wide range of characters which can be safely encoded and kept in the database in cases where special chars are unavoidable. For example picking an embed from a website (very much allowed) which may contain any of these characters;

```
/ = %2F 
: = %3A
# = %23
% = %25
? = %3F
```

When someone pastes a link that contains certain characters or tries to hyperlink some words that contain characters like the ones above(excluding %2F) the string is truncated. After doing inspection at various levels I noticed the string successfully gets to the back-end function it's then  truncated before being saved. I don't know if its **Laravel** (the parser) or its **MySql** (the database I use) that truncates these strings. Here is a particular case;

When this Facebook embed :

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_embed.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ftonyelumelu%2Fposts%2F10154627801036949%3Fcomment_id%3D10154629134011949&include_parent=false" width="560" height="201" style="border:none;overflow:hidden"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

Is pasted in the editor this is what is found in the database

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_embed.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/tonyelumelu/posts/10154627801036949?comment_id=10154629134011949
```

Careful observation will show you that all `'%2F'` was replace in the string with `'/'` but the string was exactly truncated at '%3F' which was supposed to replaced with `'?'` or at least left unchanged.

I know those are security measures but I have tweaked the front editor alot already and I think the back end sanitation should be left for me to do it (if I want) the way I want. I really need to first know how to stop such an annoying behavior before getting advice on the best practice. I would just like the strings to get into the database the way it comes without any changes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just tested, when I save the html code, I see it correctly saved into database. Looks like it is your editor issue.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan you should submit the data using a form (a laravel request) or pass the data in url. That would be quite specific. I have checked the data collected from the editor and its complete from the front end. So whatever happens should be at the backend

Comment: As you can see in my answer, now I pass data using a form. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trying to repeat the bug**

I create a test route `Route::any('/test', 'IndexController@test')->name('test');`

Then - test action:

```
public function test(Request $request) {
    if($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $er = \App\Entity::create([
            'log' => $request->code,
        ]);


        exit('done');
    }

    echo "<form method=post>" . csrf_field() . 
         "<textarea name=code></textarea><input type=submit></form>";
}
```

**Results**

When I submit your code, I can see it unaltered in Network tab of browser

[image]

Then I go to the database and see the code unaltered as well.

[image]

**What does it mean**

Unfortunally, I was unable to repeat the bug you presented here. It means it is not Laravel who transforms your code unexpectedly. Try to check Network tab and `dd()` request vars to check them. I suppose that the bug is somewhere before sending data via network.

Comment: thanks for your time! You are right the problem was at the front end. In case you like to know what was going wrong at front end here we go:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269141/javascript-truncating-string-during-concatenation/46304735#46304735