# Javascript truncating string during concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have problems with string truncation in my app built with laravel and JS(jquery). At first I thought it was a back end problem (and I asked this question:[Laravel Truncating Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45761853/laravel-truncating-strings-with-special-characters)). After careful debugging I noticed there's something wrong in my JS code.

I am trying to pass some string from CKEditor via a JQuery post(AJAX) request to the backend, However in some cases the string is truncated especially with embeds that contains special characters!

**Here is the snippet where problems occurs**

```
var content = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
alert("Content :" + content + "<br> Length :" + content.length);

var data = 'post_id=' + post_id + '&content=' + content + '&_token=' + $('#token').val();
alert("Data :" + data);
alert("Content Again :" + content);
```

**What's happening?**

1. I get string from CKEditor
2. Alert the content and the length for debugging and all looks good
3. I concatenate content to the data variable which is later sent in an ajax
   request
4. alert data shows truncated string in certain cases
5. I check content again its all good but for some reason data was
       truncated.

**Example ???**

I paste this facebook embed in the editor

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_embed.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ftonyelumelu%2Fposts%2F10154690113371949%3Fcomment_id%3D10154690136096949&include_parent=false" width="560" height="161" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Alerting the content shows the correct result without truncating. **But** alerting the data variable gives

```
Data :post_id='+post_id+'&content=<p><iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_embed.php?href=https%3A%2F
```

clearly the string is being cut around `%2F` sometimes `%3A` (another embed I tried)

**How data variable looks with normal string (`<p> This is some string </p>` )**

```
Data :post_id='+post_id+'&content=<p>This is some string</p>
&_token='+$('#token').val()
```

Please, what am I doing wrong? and generally how can I avoid such truncation in JS I have seen strings truncated several times in different situations that really hard to explain. Thanks in advance

Comment: i mean... you're building a param string manually without encoding the values... of course it's gonna have problems. `$.param()` could help, so could `encodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 2):

If `content` has especial characters, let's say it's something like `You & I forever`, then your `data` variable would look like this:

```
post_id=1&content=You & I forever&_token=bla
```

See the problem? Content is ending right after `You`, because the ampersand isn't encoded. So you should do something like this:

```
var data = 'post_id=' + post_id + '&content=' + encodeURIComponent(content) + '&_token=' + $('#token').val();
```

With that, your `data` variable would look like this:

```
post_id=1&content=You%20%26%20I%20forever&_token=bla
```

And it would all work smoothly

Comment: you are right! All I have to do now is test you method see how effective it works and mark your answer as the accepted answer. Because using the encodeURIComponent() is sure a shorter way and probably more efficient.

Comment: I believe it's going to work. Your other method also works because the browser by default encodes the values of the fields for you, but it can't do the same with strings you create on your own

Answer (score 0):

### Update

@Piyin's answer above is a better and cleaner way to do it! However I leave my long and boring method it may save for another purpose.

### Older Solution (not cool :) )

Because I needed to fix this problem as quick as possible (in production lol) I used this work around! Until we get a better answer if you are in trouble you can use this :)

**1) Create a hidden form**

```
<form id="content-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="content-post-id">
  <input type="hidden" name="content" id="content">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
</form>
```

**2) Use JQuery (or whatever) to pass the data to this form**

```
 var post_id = $('#post-id').val(); //get post id
 $('#content-post-id').val(post_id); //put in form
 var content = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData(); //get content
 $('#content').val(content); //put in form
```

**3) Serialize the form with JQuery `.serialize()` (Instead of "manually" doing it)**

```
var data = $('#content-form').serialize();
```

If you are not using JQuery this may not be cool except you have a substitute for serialize in whatever you are using!

*This may not be a good solution but it works! Am sure looking in depth (code) what the serialize() function does can help me(or maybe you) understand how to correctly serialize data in complex situations like the one I had.*